# Why my AsyncTask is doing network operation on Main Thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I have an AsyncTask inside a fragment, there is no error in the code but even the AsyncTask is performing the network operation on the main thread. 
The AsyncTask does executes but I can't figure out why it is performing the newtwork operation on the main thread.
Here is my code:

```
 public class Tappal extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

//codes of Tappal class

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;

        int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        if (position == 1) {Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new MyTask().execute("key", "id");

        } else if (position == 2)
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        else
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, HttpResponse> {
        HttpResponse httpresponse = null;
        HttpEntity httpentity = null;
        String response = null;

        protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress("Getting Tappal Details...");
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://***/***/***/****/");
            try {
                httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                publishProgress(e.toString());
            }
            return httpresponse;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... i) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), i[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse r) {
            try {
                httpentity = r.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);
                JSONObject t = new JSONObject(response);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JSON GOT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How do you figure out its on the main thread?

Comment: @Raghunandan By toasting e.toString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause you work with HttpResponse in onPostExecute(). onPostExecute do work in main thread.
Try this:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    HttpResponse httpresponse = null;
    HttpEntity httpentity = null;
    String response = null;

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress("Getting Tappal Details...");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://***/***/***/****/");
        JSONObject t = null;
        try {
            httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            httpentity = r.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);
            t = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            publishProgress(e.toString());
        }
        return t;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... i) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), i[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject r) {
        if(r != null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JSON GOT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Do work with response
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

> `onPostExecute(Result)`, invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

In your case you are processing the httpresponse in the `onPostExecute(Result)` method. You have to move this part of code in the `doInBackground` method.

You can try it debugging your code.
If you try to use a breakpoint in the doInBackground you will see the a separate Thread.

[image]

Doing the same on the onPostExecute code you will see the MainThread.

[image]